# How to use ES6 arrow functions with promise binding (bluebird)

Tags: ecmascript-6, bluebird

I'm using babel's [require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) in node to leverage ES6 but I'm running into some challenges with arrow functions in bluebird promise chains.

I use `.bind({})` at the top of my promise chain with an empty object to create shared state where I can store previous values until I need them further down the chain. Bluebird explains this usage as a "[useful side purpose](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise)".

When I switch to arrow functions, I can no longer use shared state because arrow functions use lexical `this` which is `undefined` in babel (babel automatically runs in strict mode).

Working example: https://jsbin.com/veboco/edit?html,js,console

ES6 example (not working): https://jsbin.com/menivu/edit?html,js,console

Is there any way to take advantage of arrow functions in this situation? In my code I call these methods from within an object method - shouldn't `this` be defined as the object from which the method is called?

Comment: The whole point of arrow functions is that they inherit the parent `this` instead, so you're basically asking for them not to do what they were designed to do. Why not make a parent variable in the outer scope, or write your code without the shared state object instead? Plus `.bind` isn't ES6 standard so you're locking yourself into Bluebird.

Comment: Got it. I should remove .bind() from all my promise chain calls. Is there any disadvantage to using a parent variable outside the promise chain? I'm thinking I will just do something like `const state = {}` and use that to store values.

Comment: There isn't really any downside compared to what you are doing with bind, but I'll second all of Bergi's "However" section below. Having external state is something I'd consider a bad idea when working with promises. It is much better to flatten everything as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain/28250704#28250704.

Comment: @loganfsmyth How do you feel about his example regarding generator functions in ES6? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250697/129705

Comment: `co` and such are great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want lexically bound `this`, there's no need to use arrow functions. If you *want* dynamically bound `this`, just *don't* use arrow functions.

Of course, you could scrap that `.bind({})` as a whole and use arrow functions that are bound to the object by putting everything in an object method (or an IIFE in your example):

```
(function() {
  this; // the value that everything is bound to
  double(2).then(result => {
    this.double = result; // store result here
    return triple(2);
  }).then(result => {
    console.log('double:', this.double);
    console.log('triple:', result);
    console.log('sum:', this.double + result);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
}.call({}));
```

However, there are [much better ways to access previous results in a promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) than [contextual state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250700/1048572), especially if you are [using ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250697/1048572)!

Comment: I looked through each of your examples. It seems like using a parent variable outside the chain is not a good solution because it introduces mutable state. If I learn how to use generators, would that solution be relatively future proofed? At this point I think the fastest solution would be to break the chain.

Comment: Yes, generators should be relatively future-proof, though you'd actually expect to replace them with async/await eventually. (They won't suddenly stop working of course, if that's what you mean).